# How to change the color of just the first row of TableView in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

I am using `TableView` of `QtQuick.Controls 1.4`
This is the `rowDelegate`. I want to have just the first row of blue colour and rest of the rows (empty or non-empty) of green color.

```
rowDelegate:  
           Rectangle
           {
                border.width: 1
                height: 50
                width: 2000

                color: {
                         var item = mymodel.get( styleData.row )

                         if (item.index1 === "1")
                             return "blue"

                         return "green"

                     }
             }
```

Now, my problem is that this code does colour the first row as blue but it also colours the empty rows as blue.

**What is the way to solve this problem?**

[image]

Comment: @scopchanov Why did you remove the word QML from the title?

Comment: The question is already tagged as QML. There is no need to duplicate that in the title.

Comment: @scopchanov There is a need. When the questions appear in "similar questions" list or in google search, the tag is not visible in these cases and people's time gets wasted in knowing that they didn't or did want this solution for QML.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251861/5366641

Comment: From that answer: `As such, tags only have a place in the title if they are an organic part of it:` . In my case it is a part of the question. It is a part of the sentence. I haven't used it as [QML] etc. I will revert the question back to its original form. @scopchanov

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Again, from your new link: `The title would be much more well-received if rewritten like this` That example shows that it is okay to write the language name if it is a part of the sentence. @scopchanov

Comment: Trust me on this, it is better without the tag. I mean, you will revert it now. I will say ok and leave it. Someone else will come by later and remove it. You will revert it again... Would you like to be engaged in this?

Comment: @scopchanov I will talk about this in meta if someone else comes and changes the title. Please leave it alone for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

The documentation of [`rowDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#rowDelegate-prop) says:

> Note: For performance reasons, created delegates can be recycled
> across multiple table rows. This implies that when you make use of
> implicit properties such as styleData.row or model, these values can
> change after the delegate has been constructed. This means that you
> should not assume that content is fixed when Component.onCompleted is
> called, but instead **rely on bindings to such properties.**

Note: The emphasis is mine.

### Solution

The emphasized part of the citation shows the solution, i.e. create a binding to `styleData.row`:

```
rowDelegate: Rectangle {
    color: (styleData.row === 0) ? "blue" : "green"
    width: 2000
    height: 40
    border.width: 1
}
```

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 320
    height: 200
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("TableView")

    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: libraryModel

        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            color: (styleData.row === 0) ? "blue" : "green"
            width: 2000
            height: 40
            border.width: 1
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
            width: 200
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

The provided example produces the following result:

[image: Table View]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation a while ago. For this I used `headerDelegate` to make the same work out. Here is an example:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
style:TableViewStyle {
    rowDelegate: Rectangle{
        id:rowRectangle
        color:"green"
        width: 2000
        height: 40

    }

    headerDelegate: Rectangle{
        height: 40
        width: 2000
        color: "blue"    
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though that this will set the empty rows to green. You can maybe adjust the table height based on number of entries in your model.

Comment: How will this help? I want the row to become blue not the header.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl looks like I understood the question wrong in that case. My apologies.